# Can I marry my sister-in-law after my wife's death?

Tags: nikah, mahram

I am from lahore pakistan my question is can i marry my sali ( wife younger sister )
My wife died few months back i have 2 small kids i am 40 year old my family and my inlaws family want me to marry my sali ( wifes younger sister ) when i got married my sali was only 10 year old i always treat her like my child now she is 20 my family says we should marry for the sake of my little childrens

Comment: IMO, it is love that leads to marriage, not the fact you have kids or not. You said you have somehow a "paternal" feeling/relationship with that girl, so .. In addition to this, there is a solution for your kids: if you can not take care of them, then simply employ an other person to take care of them. Here in Europe, lot of countries provide money every month for fathers who want to stop working and take care of their kids.

Comment: I've answered according to what is permissible and impermissible in Islamic law. Whether or not you *should* marry her because of your feelings, kids and age-difference etc. are subjective and not something anyone here can advise you on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I marry my wife's sister, who is widow now?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29670/can-i-marry-my-wifes-sister-who-is-widow-now)

Answer (score 3):

You can marry your sister-in-law after your wife's death, because the prohibition is only in having marriage with two sisters simultaneously.

> حُرِّمَتْ عَلَيْكُمْ ... وَأَن تَجْمَعُوا بَيْنَ الْأُخْتَيْنِ
>
> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are ... that you take [in marriage] two sisters simultaneously
>
> <sub>[Quran 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23)</sub>

This is different from your wive's mother and daughters who are perpetually forbidden once the marriage is consummated, as expressed in the same verse.

> حُرِّمَتْ عَلَيْكُمْ ... وَأُمَّهَاتُ نِسَائِكُمْ وَرَبَائِبُكُمُ اللَّاتِي فِي حُجُورِكُم مِّن نِّسَائِكُمُ اللَّاتِي دَخَلْتُم بِهِنَّ
>
> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are  ... your wives' mothers, and your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in.
>
> <sub>[Quran 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23)</sub>

Also relevant : [Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/who-are-the-women-that-a-man-is-forbidden-to-marry)

Comment: I think this answer can has the merit of a correct answer which mentioned Quranic verses well. God bless you.